# No Module named 'datetime' in python3 when creating a recipe for Yocto but datetime exists in python2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

#### host machine

Debian 9.4 Server

#### Yocto branch

`krogoth`, `BitBake Build Tool Core version 1.30.0`

#### workflow tool

`devtool`

#### Requirements

They should be available as **python3.5** packages on the hardware

I want to create recipes for:

1. [pynmea2 v1.7.1](https://github.com/Knio/pynmea2)
2. [influxdb-python v5.2.0](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python)

I use the following steps in my `$BUILD_DIR`:

1. `devtool add pynmea2 https://github.com/Knio/pynmea2/archive/v1.7.1.tar.gz`
2. `devtool add influxdb-python  https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-python/archive/v5.2.0.tar.gz`

I get the recipes from the tools. I change the `RDEPENDS_${PN} += "python-re"` to `RDEPENDS_${PN} += "${PYTHON_PN}-re"` for all runtime dependencies and shift this information to their respective `.inc` files. The files are mentioned below in the Github Gist

#### GitHub Gists

[Gists for pynmea2 and influxdb-python](https://gist.github.com/shantanoo-desai/fc00836d399f8592a30efe1ec9c56213)

### Image creation

for local tests, I add these recipes from the `workspace` folder (created automatically by `devtool`) to the `local.conf` under `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " influxdb-python pynmea2"

and burn the image for the hardware.

### Board

On the board, I run the `python3` shell to see if I can import these packages. Here is the output from the shell:

**pynmea2**:

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Sep 25 2018, 19:27:54)
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pynmea2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pynmea2/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .types import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pynmea2/types/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .talker import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pynmea2/types/talker.py", line 3, in <module>
    from ..nmea_utils import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pynmea2/nmea_utils.py", line 2, in <module>
    import datetime
ImportError: No module named 'datetime'
```

**influxdb-python**:

```
Python 3.5.1 (default, Sep 25 2018, 19:27:54)
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import influxdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/influxdb/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .client import InfluxDBClient
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/influxdb/client.py", line 14, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import cgi
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/cgi.py", line 30, in <module>
    from email.parser import FeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
    from email import message
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/message.py", line 16, in <module>
    from email import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/email/utils.py", line 30, in <module>
    import datetime
ImportError: No module named 'datetime'
```

### Contrast

If I run the `python` command on the board and try `import datetime`, the module exists.

What is the problem? Why isn't `datetime` available as a module for `python 3.5`?

**`local.conf` snippet**

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3 python3-dev python3-enum pynmea2 influxdb-python python3-pyserial "
```

### Edit

I also explicitly added `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3-datetime"` in the `local.conf` file. But still the same error.

**`python-3.5-manifest.inc`**

```
SUMMARY_${PN}-modules="All Python modules"
RDEPENDS_${PN}-modules="${PN}-2to3 ${PN}-argparse ${PN}-asyncio ${PN}-audio ${PN}-codecs ${PN}-compile ${PN}-compression ${PN}-core ${PN}-crypt ${PN}-ctypes ${PN}-curses ${PN}-datetime ${PN}-db ${PN}-debugger ${PN}-difflib ${PN}-distutils ${PN}-doctest ${PN}-email ${PN}-enum ${PN}-fcntl ${PN}-gdbm ${PN}-html ${PN}-idle ${PN}-image ${PN}-importl
ib ${PN}-io ${PN}-json ${PN}-lang ${PN}-logging ${PN}-mailbox ${PN}-math ${PN}-mime ${PN}-mmap ${PN}-multiprocessing ${PN}-netclient ${PN}-netserver ${PN}-numbers ${PN}-pickle ${PN}-pkgutil ${PN}-pprint ${PN}-profile ${PN}-pydoc ${PN}-re ${PN}-readline ${PN}-reprlib ${PN}-resource ${PN}-selectors ${PN}-shell ${PN}-signal ${PN}-smtpd ${PN}-sqlit
e3 ${PN}-sqlite3-tests ${PN}-stringold ${PN}-subprocess ${PN}-syslog ${PN}-terminal ${PN}-tests ${PN}-textutils ${PN}-threading ${PN}-tkinter ${PN}-unittest ${PN}-unixadmin ${PN}-xml ${PN}-xmlrpc  "
ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN}-modules = "1"
```

the manifest file already has `datetime` in it? What should I change in the file if at all necessary? (should I add it in a `meta-custom` layer?)

Comment: There's centainly a `datetime` module in Python 3, maybe there's something wrong with your setup (wrong permissions?)

Comment: how do I determine permissions in yocto?

Comment: Totally unfamiliar with `Yocto` but Linux beeing linux you should see that the user running the program has at least read access to `/usr/lib/python3.5/datetime.py`. And figure out how it lost it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I saw a small snippet of [This particular blogpost](http://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/embedded-linux/yocto-project/developing-and-remote-debugging-python-app-on-yocto-linux-build) which mentions using `python-modules` in the `INSTALL_IMAGE_append`.

Having seen the `python-3.5-manifest.inc` file mentioned in the question; I saw that the `-modules` will provide me all the basic modules needed for my app to run.

### Test

Hence, in the `local.conf` file I added `IMAGE_INSTALL_appends = " python3-modules"` and loaded the image on the hardware. This infact worked perfectly.

Now in the python3 shell, I do not receive any `datetime` module errors.

### Snippet for `local.conf` now

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python3-modules influxdb-python pynmea2 pyserial"
```

This works perfect.

#### p.s.

I am not sure at this point if i should add `${PYTHON_PN}-modules` in the `RDEPENDS_${PN}` for the recipes of `influxdb-python` and `pynmea2`.

#### UPDATE

I updated the [GitHub gists](https://gist.github.com/shantanoo-desai/fc00836d399f8592a30efe1ec9c56213) which now added `${PYTHON_PN}-modules` in the `RDEPENDS` and it works on the board.

### Drawback

As a I understand adding `python3-modules` would increase your image footprint since it needs to add a lot of modules in the rootfs. But these modules seem to be important to run many types of application, so there is an upside to it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `python-3.5-manifest.inc` file inside of `source/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python-3.5-manifest.inc`

Try explicitly pulling in python-datetime with:

`IMAGE_INSTALL_append += "python3-datetime"`

Comment: I tried adding it explicitly via `IMAGE_INSTALL_append` but didn't work. I will look into the `manifest.inc`. If it isn't there could you suggest how to update the file?